# How to render all fields from a datasource containing items with title,image,description fields using controller rendering

Tags: mvc

**Controller:**

```cs
public class RotatorController : SitecoreController 
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var dataSourceId = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.DataSource;
    var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSourceId);

    var viewModel = new RotatorViewModel
    {
      RotatorItems = dataSource.Children
    };
    return View(viewModel);
  }
}
```

**View Model:**

```cs
public class RotatorViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Item> RotatorItems { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```razor
@model RotatorViewModel 

<h1>Products List</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.RotatorItems)
{
  <h2>@item.Fields["Title"]</h2>
      @item.Fields["Image"]
      @item.Fields["Description"]
}
```

**my doubt is:**

the description(discription is  a field) is of type table....but in webpage it is renderd as tags
and also for the image
[image]

can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try @html.Raw(@item.Fields["Description"])?

Comment: thank you @BalajiKuppuswamy but still the images are not getting rendered

Comment: Did you try with : @Html.Sitecore().Field("nameoffield",@item) ?What is the type of your fields?

Comment: What do you hardcode?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber thank you now its working

Comment: If is correct please mark Filip answer as correct. Is the same what I told you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use Sitecore's MVC equivalent of a FieldRenderer (more information can be found here: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/sitecore-mvc/rendering-content/)

```
@model RotatorViewModel 

<h1>Products List</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.RotatorItems)
{
  <h2>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", item)</h2>
      @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image", item)
      @Html.Sitecore().Field("Description", item)
}
```

This will make sure that all your fields output the proper HTML tags. I advise against outputting it manually, even using `@Html.Raw(item.Fields["Description"])` for the html formatted content as you're not expanding links in this case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use :

```
@model RotatorViewModel 

<h1>Products List</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.RotatorItems)
{
  <h2>@item.Fields["Title"]</h2>
      @item.Fields["Image"]
      @item.Fields["Description"]
}
```